# WordPress Custom URL Structure Causes Weird Results When Visiting Non Existent Page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

We are creating a website in WordPress and we need a unique ID in the permalink structure for a jobs post type. The permalink structure looks like this: http://headway.xpandcreative.co.uk/jobs/5934-sales-executive-4/

With the ID at the front being the post ID. The problem is, if we go to a URL like: http://headway.xpandcreative.co.uk/jobs/5934-sales-executive-4dediejidjiedjiejdiendjeijdejdjie/  it still displays the job even though it should clearly be a 404.

The code I use to create this permalink structure is:

```
// Rewrite permalink structure
function jobs_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $queryarg = 'post_type=jobs&p=';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%cpt_id%', '([^/]+)', $queryarg );
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct( 'jobs', '/jobs/%cpt_id%/', false );
}
add_action( 'init', 'jobs_rewrite' );

function jobs_permalink( $post_link, $id = 0, $leavename ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
//     $post = &get_post( $id );
    global $post;
    if ( is_wp_error( $post ) )
        return $post;
        $newlink = $wp_rewrite->get_extra_permastruct( 'jobs' );
        $newlink = str_replace( '%cpt_id%', $post->ID . '-' . $post->post_name, $newlink );
        $newlink = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $newlink ) );
    return $newlink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'jobs_permalink', 1, 3);
```

Please check out the website here http://headway.xpandcreative.co.uk/jobs/

Can anyone give me a suggestion on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Plugin [Debug This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-this/) may help you figuring out which rewrite rule causes the job page being loaded. I had a similar problem and solved it by deleting and inserting rewrite rules using the [rewrite_rules_array](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/rewrite_rules_array) filter and additionally manipulating the posts query by means of the [posts_where](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) filter. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have `$queryarg = 'post_type=jobs&p='` which means in your example turns into `$queryarg = 'post_type=jobs&p=5934-sales-executive-4'`.

Since `p` is intended to be post ID which type is `int`, Wordpress sanitizes the input.

I haven't searched how it is done exactly but when you try yourself to do something like:

```
$returnValue = intval('5934-sales-executive-4', 10);
```

you'll get in this case value `5934`, and I think that is happening here.

Comment: Hi @Picard thanks for your reply. You stated what the problem is but is there any solution to this? I need the url structure to be something like sales-executive-1654 in an ideal world. Was only able to get it with the id at the front but I suppose this is because I'm replacing the ID which, as you say, is an int.

Comment: You could try to parse the slug for the id like: `$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%cpt_id%', '[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\-([0-9]+)', $queryarg );` so the `$queryarg` will get only the ID which you will have at the end - you will have to test the regex, because I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Maybe I misunderstood how to implement it but it didn't work for me.